# NavigatorIOS onRightButtonPress Access View Data

Tags: react-native

I have a view which I want users to be able to select multiple items. After selecting items I want them to click Done in the top right and be taken to the next screen. Using Swift I hooked into prepareForSegue and segue.destinationViewController to make it happen.

With React Native, I'm using the NavigatorIOS onRightButtonPress function but unsure how to access View data to use within the passProps.

The code currently looks like this:

```js
return (<NavigatorIOS
  ref="nav"
  style={styles.nav}
  initialRoute={{
    nav: this.refs.nav,
    component: this.props.onSuccessView,
    title: 'What Would You Like To Do?',
    rightButtonTitle: 'Next',
    onRightButtonPress: () => {this.refs.nav.navigator.push({
          title: "Where To Go",
          backButtonTitle: 'Back',
          component: SuggestionsView
       });
    }
  }}
/>);
```

What I want is for this.props.onSuccessView.onRightButtonPress to handle which component should be called and provide the props. Is this possible?

If not, can I call a function such as props: this.props.onSuccessView.getProps() ?

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 1):

This smells weird. Are you sure this is what you want to do? Why not pass a callback from the parent component that has awareness of the children you show here - then you could use refs to you what you need by grabbing the children and acting upon them.

Alternatively: look at [the example](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html#content) for NavigatorIOS and see how the router is used - the pop and push methods do feel like a better fit for what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thanks, it could be a smell.  I'm not sure how the callback would work, do you have any examples?  Do you mean similar to passProps: {route: this.props.route} or https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/createExamplePage.js ?

My idea was that I want the view itself to be responsible of where it goes next and the data, not the view initalising it.

Answer (score 1):

A. In initial component

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'title',
    component: MyComponent,
    rightButtonTitle: 'rightButton',
    passProps: {
        ref: (component) => {this.pushedComponent = component},
    },
    onRightButtonPress: () => {
        // Access View Data
        this.pushedComponent && this.pushedComponent.props.someObject...;
    },
});
```

B. In pushed component 
replace onRightButtonPress func in pushed component.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    // get current route
    var route = this.props.navigator.navigationContext.currentRoute;
    // update onRightButtonPress func
    route.onRightButtonPress =  () => {
        // Access View Data
        this.props.someObject...
    };
    // component will not rerender
    this.props.navigator.replace(route);
},
```